# Does the following inequality hold - the inner product divided by the product of norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products, triangle-inequality

Let $\cdot$ denotes the dot product and $||\boldsymbol{x}||$ denotes the $L^2-$norm of the vector $\boldsymbol{x}$. Suppose $\boldsymbol{a,b,c}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Does the following inequality hold?
$$\left\|\frac{a\cdot b}{||a||*||b||} \right\|+\left\|\frac{b\cdot c}{||b||*||c||} \right\| \geq \left\|\frac{a\cdot c}{||a||*||c||} \right\|$$
If yes, how to prove it? Thanks!

**Edit:** There are two additional conditions that I should add to the above setup

1. $\boldsymbol{a,b,c}$ are not orthogonal to each other
2. $\boldsymbol{a,b,c}$ are different vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$
3. $\boldsymbol{a,b,c}$ are not parallel to each other

Comment: a.b is a scalar. Why does the notation show an L2 norm around the dot product?

Comment: @JayaramIyer In this case, the L2 norm is the same as the L1 norm, so I just wrote it as the L2 norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $a = c$ and $b$ orthogonal to $a$ (and hence also $c$) then the RHS is $1$ and the LHS is $0$.

**Edit for the updated question**

No the inequality still wont hold. Let $v \neq 0$ be any vector that is not parallel or perpendicular to $a$ and let $a^{\perp}$ be a vector orthogonal to $a$. Then for $\epsilon > 0$ define $b = a^{\perp} + \epsilon v$ and $c = a + \epsilon v$. Then the LHS and RHS are both continuous functions of $\epsilon$ and the vectors are different, not parallel and non perpendicular. We have
$$
a \cdot b = \epsilon a \cdot v \\
a \cdot c = \|a\|^2 + \epsilon a \cdot v \\
b \cdot c = \epsilon (a^{\perp} \cdot v  + v \cdot a + \epsilon v \cdot v)
$$
Thinking about the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ we see that the LHS goes to $0$ but the RHS does not. As we have continuity there must be some $\epsilon>0$ for which the inequality does not hold. You can use this construction with explicit vectors to find such an epsilon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have edited the question a little bit in that $a,b,c$  are not orthogonal or parallel to each other, and $a,b,c$ are different vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Would the inequality hold under the new setup?

Comment: Updated the answer